# Aligning text in Haskell

Tags: strings, haskell, formatting

This Haskell program just aligns the text lines on the given substrings.

I took inspiration from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57786/aligning-lines), but my code is not golfed.

```
import Data.Function
import Data.Ord
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

alignOn :: String -> [String] -> [String]
alignOn char lines = map padline lines
  where 
    partBeforechar = head . splitOn char
    longestLengthBeforeChar = maximum $ map (length . partBeforechar) lines
    padline line = replicate offset ' ' ++ line
      where
        offset = longestLengthBeforeChar - (length (partBeforechar line))

main = do
  mapM putStrLn $ alignOn "," ["Programming, Puzzles", "And, Code Golf"]
  mapM putStrLn $ alignOn ", " ["Code, Review", "And Other, improvements"]
  mapM putStrLn $ alignOn "abc" ["Example abc bar", "foo abc Example"]
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Programming, Puzzles
>         And, Code Golf
>
>      Code, Review
> And Other, improvements
>
> Example abc bar
>     foo abc Example
> ```

Comment: Can you specify the kind of code review you’re waiting for this code ? Code formatting, speed optimization, tips and tricks, functional approach… ?

Comment: @zigazou anything.

Answer (score 3):

### Use -Wall

When you are evaluating your code, you should use Haskell `-Wall` verbosity.

```
ghc -Wall mycode.hs
```

or

```
runghc -Wall mycode.hs
```

For example, it will tell you:

- Unneeded `import`s (the import of ... is redundant)
- Inappropriate use of variable names (this binding for ... shadows the existing binding)
- Missing type signatures (top-level binding with no type signature ...)
- etc.

This is generally good advice.

Specifying imported functions and types in `import` statements helps future reading of your code to determine why a particular `import` is needed.

For example:

```
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
```

### Use hlint

`hlint` is another useful tool to help you improve your code. For example, it would tell you that parentheses are unnecessary in the following case:

```
longestLengthBeforeChar - (length (partBeforechar line))
```

That could be replaced by:

```
longestLengthBeforeChar - length (partBeforechar line)
```

Or that, you shouldn’t use `mapM` if you don’t intend to use the result. You should use `mapM_` (note the underscore) to make it clear.

Again, like `-Wall`, `hlint` suggestions are generally good advice you should follow.

### Factorize

When you often see a pattern in your code, it may be an alert that it needs
factorization.

For example:

```
mapM putStrLn $ alignOn "," ["Programming, Puzzles", "And, Code Golf"]
mapM putStrLn $ alignOn ", " ["Code, Review", "And Other, improvements"]
mapM putStrLn $ alignOn "abc" ["Example abc bar", "foo abc Example"]
```

could be replaced by:

```
let tests = [ (","  , ["Programming, Puzzles", "And, Code Golf"])
            , (", " , ["Code, Review", "And Other, improvements"])
            , ("abc", ["Example abc bar", "foo abc Example"])
            ]

mapM_ (putStr . unlines . uncurry alignOn) tests
```

(better: use `QuickCheck` and put the test code outside your module)

### Naming convention

You should use appropriate names for your parameters. Naming `char` a parameter which is in fact a `String` is misleading. It also does not give any indication on the role of this parameter. It could be renamed `separator`, for example.

You should also avoid to use a name that will shadow another one. You use `lines` in your function as a parameter, but `lines` is a well defined function (the counterpart of `unlines`).

### Warning

Some Haskell functions like `head` can generate exceptions:

```
head [] -- Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

When you use it in your code, you should ensure an empty list will never occur (since it comes right after the `splitOn` function, it is safe to use it).

### Coding convention

Avoid a `where` clause inside another `where` clause. It generally indicates the code should be split because your function is complex. Complex functions are harder to debug.

In fact, in your code, the `alignOn` can be splitted into independent, reusable and testable functions.

For example:

```
alignOn :: String -> [String] -> [String]
alignOn sep rows = fmap padline rows
    where padding row = longestLengthBefore sep rows - lengthBefore sep row
          padline row = replicate (padding row) ' ' ++ row

lengthBefore :: String -> String -> Int
lengthBefore sep = length . head . splitOn sep

longestLengthBefore :: String -> [String] -> Int
longestLengthBefore sep = maximum . fmap (lengthBefore sep)
```

Note:

- This example is NOT optimized.
- `fmap` should be preferred to `map` as it is more general.

### Generalizing

The padding character could be defined as a parameter.

### Optimization

You could rewrite your code to use `Text` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You only ever use the `length` of `partBeforechar`, so you should move the `(length .)` into its definition. I don't like the name `char` and would replace it with something, say, derived from the word delimiter. Consider replacing `mapM` with `unlines` later in the line.